# click event doesn't work, "co.console.log() is not a function"

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been trying to get a button to work to bring up a page, passing an object in the parameters, but for some reason, it gives me the error

> "co. is not a function."

I don't know what the problem is because it gives me the same error when I try to use `alert` or `console.log`, or anything.

page **HTML**:

```
<ion-header>

   <ion-navbar>
       <ion-title>SearchResults</ion-title>
   </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor= "let item of resultArray;">
            <img src={{item.thumbnail}} />
            <p>{{item.title}}</p>
            <button bookDetail (click)="console.log(\"Even some text, please?\")">DETAIL</button>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On your `ts` file just do like below.

**.ts**

```
log():void {
 console.log('Your message here');
}
```

**html**

```
<button ion-button (click)="log()">DETAIL</button>
```

**Note:** If you need to pass the `item` then just do like this `log(item)` on `html` side and `ts` side `log(data):void {}`.

Comment: Alright, so that hurdle's been surmounted. Now, though, I have a different issue. I'm trying to push another page based on the button clicked (basically, bringing up a details page for the item), and when I try to do so, I get an error starting with "Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Here's the function I'm trying to call:

  BookDetail(title, thumbnail):void{
     this.navCtrl.push(BookDetail, {
      bookTitle: title,
      bookImg: thumbnail
     });
    };

Comment: Can you put your new issue on your original question with using better code formatting?On comment section, no one can read it properly.

Comment: Also, give both page.html and page.ts code. Also, @Sampath, I think you have answered his question. Now, he is facing a different problem. He needs to ask a new question for this. Eoin - you should accept this and ask a new question.